# Moving Unity UI

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a single canvas, in which lives a global UI image background, and 4 frame objects.  In each frame object, there lives up to hundreds of UI images and texts.  No buttons and no colliders exist in a frame object.

During the game, scripts lerp the frames by setting "frame.transform.localPosition".  When all 4 frame objects are stationary, the frame rate is a constant 60fps.  When a frame is in motion, the fps falls to about 33 fps and pops back up as soon as the movement is done.

The profiler suggests the canvas is doing a huge amount of work.  What is going on?  Are UI elements in a canvas supposed to be static?

Picture of my scene:
http://i.imgur.com/o3pfAt3.png

Comment: what is a "frame"?  what are you referring to ?

Comment: also what is " frame is in motion"?

Comment: A frame object is just an object that is filled with UI elements.  It looks like a picture frame.  I used a poor word choice.

Comment: what is an "object"??  using the Unity documentation, show the actual class (or whatever?) you are talking about.  Random example, do you mean this: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Text.html say ??

Comment: in any event, I've explained the problem below .. you have to use the anchored position concept to move UI elements.  you **cannot** (generally) just move the transform around, it's meaningless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you are doing is what I think you are doing, you don't want a single canvas with the 4 frames inside of it, what you should be doing is having 4 canvases each being a child of one of the frame objects which you move around.

From the "Tanks" tutorial from unity, see [the video on Tank Health](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/tanks-tutorial/tank-health?playlist=20081). In that video they create a health bar that follows the tank around, I believe this is a similar effect to what you are trying to do with your frames and children of them.